# How secure is the ID resulting from this code?

Tags: c#, cryptography, base64, guid

I am generating an ID for use in my application, where users can connect to each other. for identification I am using an ID, sort of like teamviewer. I want it to both be unique and cryptographically secure/hard to guess. So I have generated a GUID, as well as 8 bytes of secure data, and simply concatenated them. My question is how secure is this ID specifically against brute force attacks? Example of an ID: dKNqrkHImQ9A9ulu8DOvYDLS3x2U8k0d

My code:

```
public static string MakeBase64ID()
{
    int postkeylength = 8; //bytes
    byte[] prekey = CreateCryptographicallySecureGuid().ToByteArray();
    byte[] postkey = CryptoRandomByteArr(postkeylength);

    byte[] ID = new byte[prekey.Length + postkeylength];
    Array.Copy(prekey, ID, prekey.Length);
    Array.Copy(postkey, 0, ID, prekey.Length, postkey.Length);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(ID);
}

public static Guid CreateCryptographicallySecureGuid()
{
    return new Guid(CryptoRandomByteArr(16));
}

public static byte[] CryptoRandomByteArr(int length)
{
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    rng.GetBytes(buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: I dont think this id `dKNqrkHImQ9A9ulu8DOvYDLS3x2U8k0d` can be bruteforced but still you could make your code better by adding special characters

Comment: what do you mean by adding special chars? the data is generated randomly, from bytes. base64 is just a way of representing it.

Comment: ya i m sorry. but i dont think it can be bruteforced

Comment: @Agent_Orange Famous last words of developers: "I don't think that…".

Comment: thanks Uwe Keim for help with the formatting.

Comment: @Uwe Keim, huh what do you mean?

Comment: @Agent_Orange what he means is you shouldnt guess or hope about something like this. and it can be brute forced. anything can. the question is how long or how much resources will it take.

Comment: See if this text(dKNqrkHImQ9A9ulu8DOvYDLS3x2U8k0d) is hashed key or encrypted key of "12345", then if some get this get this key so they will try to get 12345 plain text. But as i can see this is your id, and that ID is getting passed via network, then why do he(attacker) need to know anything else? Is it correct or i didn't understand correctly?

Comment: You go Byte[] -> Guid -> Byte[], just make `postkeylength = 24` and drop the guid in it's entirety and it will be doing the exact same thing.

Comment: but the random data is designed to be random, but not unique. im using the guid specifically because its designed to be unique. @ScottChamberlain

Comment: The GUID isn't doing anything particularly for you. It is just a datatype where you temporarily route your 16 bytes of random data. You might as well keep it in a byte array.

Comment: The guide is only unique if you call Guid.NewGuid(). If you pass in the same byte array twice it will make the same guid twice.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Guid.NewGuid() is v4 guid which is not unique in strict sense. It's just 16 random bytes, like generated by OP.

Comment: oh really? I might forgo the passing of a byte array to the guid and just call Guid.NewGuid(), since supposedly the 64 bits of randomness is enuf.

Comment: thanks for the info @ScottChamberlain and MartinSmith

Comment: No - stick with the cryptographically secure random generation and forget about the GUID

Comment: @DOSLuke if you need cryptographically random data - then do what you do now (but without Guid since as you now understand - it's useless in your implementation, OR use Guid.NewGuid + 8 bytes of random, as you originally intended). While Guid.NewGuid is random now - it's kind of implementation detail, and you don't know how random it really is. Plus - it might change in future versions. For example in older .NET it was unique (based on current machine information) and not random at all, who knows what can happen later (or on which .NET your app might run).

Comment: @Evk I actually dont need to rely on the the IDs staying consistent in how they are generated, as long as they are both unique and at least somewhat cryptographically secure. I am happy with relying on the guid part for uniqueness, and the latter part for for being secure. and It shouldnt change too much anyways since guid is just microsofts implementation of the UUID spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It contains 64 bits of cryptographic randomness. It depends on the brute forcing speed how secure this is. If it's done at 1 million attempts per second you need `2^64/1e6/86400/365=584942` years. That is very secure.

If the brute forcing has to go through the internet then the speed probably drops to 100 attempts per second as well.

64 bits are more secure than most passwords.

I like this scheme from a practical standpoint as well. This is a good system to generate IDs that cannot be guessed.

Comment: ok cool. I wasnt sure because the GUID is designed to be unique, not secure/random. so I didnt know if that would be a weakness or if only 8 bytes added on would be enough.

Comment: also thank you for saying you liked the scheme, I thought of it myself, even if I reinvented the wheel. :P

Comment: Why 64 bits if it contains 24 random bytes (so, 192 bits)?

Comment: the first bits from the guid cant be counted on for their randomness, a guid is designed to be unique, not secure. @Evk

Comment: And it is base64, if you look at the name of the first function @zaph

Comment: @DOSLuke - You seem to think that round tripping it through a GUID is doing something magical for you and guaranteeing uniqueness. It isn't. The value of `prekey` will be the same as the output `buffer` from `CryptoRandomByteArr`

Comment: indeed I did @MartinSmith

Comment: @Evk you are talking about the base64 version, right? But only 8 random bytes enter into that representation.

Comment: But OP creates "guid" from 16 crypto-random bytes, and then calls ToByteArray on that "guid", getting those 16 bytes back. So in result, code produces 24 cryptographically random bytes, not 8. So OP's intention (combine globally unique data and crypto random data) is not what actually happens in his code (even if we forget that Guid in last .NET versions is also just 16 random bytes and not actually unique).

Comment: @Evk I see. Then it's 16 crypto bytes. The generator does not output more than 16. Can't be more. And the Guid is not necessary. I did not notice.

Comment: 24 because they call it twice. Once with 16 and once with 8 and concatenate the results.

Comment: So much confusion.